# onCreateOptionsMenu() override not being called in BaseActivity

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-toolbar

My base activity displays the toolbar but has no title, burger or overflow menus on the bar. I can not figure out how to get the menus to show. Any help would be much appreciated! onCreateOptionsMenu() is not being called in the base activity when I debug.

BaseActivity

```
public abstract class BaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity
    implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_base);

        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
               this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, 
               R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) 
        findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void setContentView(int layoutResID) {
        final DrawerLayout fullView = (DrawerLayout) 
        getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.activity_base, null);
        FrameLayout activityContainer = (FrameLayout) 
        fullView.findViewById(R.id.activity_content);
        getLayoutInflater().inflate(layoutResID, activityContainer, true);
        super.setContentView(fullView);
   }

   @Override
   public void onBackPressed() {
       DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
       if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
           drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
       } else {
           super.onBackPressed();
       }
   }

   @Override
   public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
       super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
       getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
       return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
   }
}
```

myActivity

```
public class myActivity extends BaseActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_scan_item);
    }
}
```

Any idea what I am missing to make this work? I have read around and am really struggling to fix this!

My app_bar_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.mpd.sfs.BaseActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: You must `return true;` from `onCreateOptionsMenu()` for the menu to be created. Aside from that, you're calling `super.setContentView()` from the derived `Activity`, so the `activity_base` layout you initially load and set up in `BaseActivity` is going to be completely replaced in your `setContentView()` override. Remove the `fullView` inflation and `super.setContentView(fullView);` call there, and just inflate `layoutResID` into the existing `FrameLayout`. That is, call `findViewById(R.id.activity_content)` directly, instead of on `fullView`.

Comment: You'll also need to call `super.setContentView(R.layout.activity_base);` in `BaseActivity`'s `onCreate()`.

Comment: Thank you so much. Life saver :) All works nicely now